# How to keep built in Windows apps up to date?

Tags: group-policy, windows-store, microsoft-store, intune

I am currently going through our On-Premise GPO's and migrating them to Intune. I am currently looking at the MS Store specifically

Please see below for my current test settings in Intune that are applied at user level

[image]

I would like help with the below questions if possible ?

1. I would like to know the best way to stop users from accessing the MS Store while ensuring that built in Windows apps e.g. camera and calculator are kept up to date?
2. I would also like to know how this process happens regarding the built in applications that are built in and not deployed via Intune.
3. Why the message displayed when trying to access the MS Store has changed from "Blocke" to "Something" went wrong.

Comment: Blocking the MS-Store via Intune or Group Policy requires a Windows Enterprise edition.

Comment: we have enterprise

Comment: Have you tried this [method](https://www.joeyverlinden.com/block-the-microsoft-store-via-intune-windows-11/)?